# Loopback - How to implement different type of users

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm developing an app for a school and I decide to develop my Web Api using Loopback. My app have two kind of users: Teachers and Students. I noticed that the Loopback gives my a User Model by default and It seems it can not be changed. How can I implement this? Making 2 other tables Teacher and Students and relate them to Users table? If I do this, Am i able to set security rules then using this tables? How can I do it?

Thanks you very much

Comment: Note that you can't change built-in models (e.g. User), but you can [extend](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models) them, which is a very common scenario. That being said, I would go with [roles](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles), like @Medet proposed, because being Teacher/Student is indeed a role of a user. They both have username, email, password etc. They just have different capabilities. At least that's how it looks on a first sight. It always depends on your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create different user table unless there is drastical difference between `loopback:user`, because loopback gives a lot of built-in helpers (email verification, password recovery, password strength, unique username). In your case you better use roles, [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles)

```
//create user
User.create({
    username: 'Obama', 
    email: 'obama@doe.com', 
    password: 'opensesame'
}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    //create the teacher role
    Role.create({
      name: 'teacher'
    }, function(err, role) {
      if (err) cb(err);

      //make obama a teacher
      role.principals.create({
        principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
        principalId: user.id //obama id
      }, function(err, principal) {
        cb(err);
      });
    });
  });
```

Then if you want some route(let's say *lessons*) to have access only for teachers, then add config to `models/lesson.json` model

```
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "teacher", // <== role
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "find" 
}
```